# sort array tables with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm doing an exercise where ihave to read data from a table and guard in Arrays to sort the sequence :

1. Available, Buy;
2. Available, No stock;
3. Sold, Buying;
4. Sold, No Stock.

Could someone help me saying how to do to read the two cell of the same line then distribute between arrays and generate a new table already ordered?
My code below:

```
 <table id="giftreg-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>prod0</th>
            <th>sold</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>prod0</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>prod2</td>
            <td>sold</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod2</td>
            <td>sold</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod4</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>no Stock</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>prod6</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod2</td>
            <td>sold</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod5</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod3</td>
            <td>sold</td>
            <td>buy</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod4</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>no Stock</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>prod4</td>
            <td>available</td>
            <td>no Stock</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="sortTable()">Order</button>

        <script>
            var TableIDvalue = "giftreg-table";
            var TableLastSortedColumn = -1;

            var arrayOldTable = new Array();
            var arrayNewTable = new Array();
            var arrayTitle = new Array();
            var arrayFirst = new Array();
            var arraySecond = new Array();
            var arrayThird = new Array();
            var arrayFourth = new Array();



            function sortTable() {
                var _sold = /sold/gi;
                var _noStock = /no Stock/gi;
                var _available = /available/gi;
                var _buy = /buy/gi;

                var table = document.getElementById("giftreg-table");

                var line;

                for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    line = "";
                    for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
                        var cell = row.cells[j];

                        line += cell.innerHTML;

                    }
                    if (line.search(_available, _buy) == -1) {
                        arrayFirst[i] = linha

                    }

                    if (rows.indexOf(_available, _noStock)) {
                        arraySecond[i] = line;
                    }
                    if (rows.indexOf(_sold, _buy)) {
                        arrayThird[i] = line;
                    }
                    if (rows.indexOf(_sold, _noStock)) {
                        arrayFourth[i] = line;
                    } else {
                        arrayTitle[i] = line;
                    }

                }
                //NewTable();
                arrayNewTable[0] = arrayTitle;
                arrayNewTable[1] = arrayFirst;
                arrayNewTable[2] = arraySecond;
                arrayNewTable[3] = arrayThird;
                arrayNewTable[4] = arrayFourth;
                //var newTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {

                    document.writeln(arrayNewTable[i]);
                }
                createTable(arrayNewTable);

            }

            function createTable(newTable) {
                var table = document.createElement('table'),
                    tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

                tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
                    var row = document.createElement('tr');

                    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
                        var cell = document.createElement('td');
                        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
                        row.appendChild(cell);
                    });

                    tableBody.appendChild(row);
                });

                table.appendChild(tableBody);
                document.body.appendChild(table);
            }
        </script>
```

look here put an example that I think is most visible for you to understand my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Helder666/yzmp2psz/2/ (note: this coloqueo linck in the commentary below also)

Comment: Have a look at https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: Please explain better and give an out put example of what your expecting

Comment: look here put an example that I think is most visible for you to understand my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Helder666/yzmp2psz/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be what you need:

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <table id="giftreg-table" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
           <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>prod0</th>
               <th>sold</th>
               <th>Quantity</th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>

           <tr>
               <td>prod0</td>
               <td>available</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>prod2</td>
               <td>sold</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td>prod2</td>
               <td>sold</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td>prod4</td>
               <td>available</td>
               <td>no Stock</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>prod6</td>
               <td>available</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td>prod2</td>
               <td>sold</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>prod3</td>
               <td>sold</td>
               <td>no Stock</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>prod5</td>
               <td>available</td>
               <td>buy</td>
           </tr>



            </tbody>
       </table>    
    <button onclick="sortTable()">Order</button>

           <script>
               var TableIDvalue = "giftreg-table";
               var TableLastSortedColumn = -1;
            var availableArray = new Array();
            var soldArray = new Array();
            var _sold = /sold/i;
            var _noStock = /no Stock/i;
            var _available = /available/i;
            var _buy = /buy/i;
            var head,tail,result;

            function sortTable()
            {
                var sold,quantity;
                var table = document.getElementById("giftreg-table");
                for (i=1;i< table.rows.length;i++)
                {
                    row= table.rows[i];
                    sold=row.cells[1].innerHTML;

                    result=_available.test(sold);
                    console.log ("i="+i+",sold=" + sold +","+result);
                    if (result)
                        availableArray.push(i)
                    else
                        soldArray.push(i)
                }
                head="";
                tail="";

                var newTable = document.createElement("table");
                newTable.setAttribute("border","1"); 
                newTable.setAttribute("cellpadding","10"); 
                newTable.setAttribute("cellspacing","0"); 
                newTable.setAttribute("style","border-collapse:collapse;");
                for (i=0;i<availableArray.length;i++)
                {

                    row= table.rows[availableArray[i]];
                    quantity=row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    result=_buy.test(quantity);
                    if (_buy.test(quantity))
                        head=head+"<tr>"+row.innerHTML+"</tr>";
                    else
                        tail=tail+"<tr>"+row.innerHTML+"</tr>";
                }
                head=head+tail;
                tail="";
                for (i=0;i< soldArray.length;i++)
                {

                    row= table.rows[soldArray[i]];
                    quantity=row.cells[2].innerHTML;
                    result=_buy.test(quantity)
                    if (_buy.test(quantity))
                        head=head+"<tr>"+row.innerHTML+"</tr>";
                    else
                        tail=tail+"<tr>"+row.innerHTML+"</tr>";
                }
                newTable.innerHTML=head+tail;
                document.body.appendChild(newTable);
            }
           </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Thank you That really helped, however if not too much to ask, as I would to read only the table tbody and then generate the ordered elements of the new tbody in the same place of the old tbody, where to stay only one table on the screen?

Comment: I put so at the end of the function "document.getElementById (" div-table ") appendChild (newtable);." however I am without the table title bar, so I wonder if the cause tbody

Comment: I got it, put :"[ title= row= table.rows[0].innerHTML;
        newTable.innerHTML=title+head+tail;
       document.getElementById("div-table").appendChild(newTable);]"